# Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

When I try to create a new self-host runner in GitHub actions, I am always getting Below error;

Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1

- Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/dow ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
  eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
  ```

I am using this script:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.303.0/actions-runner-win-x64-2.303.0.zip -OutFile actions-runner-win-x64-2.303.0.zip

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?